# how to handle mixed datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have large csv data file containing few columns with mixed data type, Integer and String with mathematical operators.
for example.

```
column1  column2
70        90
60+3      50
80        30-4
90+5      40+7
45-4      60
50+5      56
50-5      32+20
```

Is there anyway in pandas dataframe that I can read column values as Integer only?
I want to read string values as output of operation.

Desired output should be,

```
column1   column2
70          90
63          50
80          26
95          47
41          60
55          56
45          52
```

Thanks in advance!
DP

Comment: You would need to evaluate the operations. While `eval()` would be able to do that, I'd **strongly advise against** passing the strings directly to it – at the very least ensure there's only numbers, spaces and mathematical operators in the strings...

Comment: Thanks AKX! it looks code is working.

Answer (score 0):

(To expand on my comment...)

You will need to evaluate the expressions.

While [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) is be able to do that, it's also able to evaluate *any* arbitrary Python code, including things that will steal your secrets, destroy your system, etc.

Thus, you'll need to make sure there's nothing untoward in there; below, I'm using a regexp to ensure all characters in the string are either digits or one of the fundamental mathematical operators. (The `eval()` call can still fail due to invalid syntax, e.g. `3*/3`, or it can take a long time or result in a big, big value (`333**999`).)

The `data` here is self-contained for example's sake, but naturally you can read it in from a file or whatnot.

```
import io
import re

import pandas as pd

CSV_DATA = """
column1;column2
70;90
60+3;50
80;30-4
90+5;40+7
45-4;60
50+5;56
50-5;32+20
""".strip()

safe_re = re.compile("^[-+*/0-9]+$")

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(CSV_DATA), sep=";")


def maybe_evaluate(val):
    if isinstance(val, str):
        if val.isdigit():
            # already only numbers, coerce to integer
            return int(val)
        if safe_re.match(val):
            # should be safe to evaluate (only numbers and operators)
            return eval(val)
    # Otherwise, return the value as-is (you could raise an error here)
    return val


data["column1"] = data["column1"].apply(maybe_evaluate)
data["column2"] = data["column2"].apply(maybe_evaluate)

print(data)
```

This prints out

```
   column1  column2
0       70       90
1       63       50
2       80       26
3       95       47
4       41       60
5       55       56
6       45       52
```

as expected.

Comment: Hi AKX, yesterday i tried your code and looks working if I apply function to individual column, but it does not work if I try to apply function to multiple columns . I tried data[["column1","column2"]] = data[["column1","column2"]].apply(maybe_evaluate), but it returns same values as input.

Comment: You'll need to apply it column by column; otherwise the `val` passed to the function will not be the string itself.

Comment: okay. I was trying to avoid no. of lines in code, as all columns in file need to be evaluated through this function. Thanks.

Comment: Well, `for col in ("column1", "column2"): data[col] = data[col].apply(maybe_evaluate)` ...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I just used for col in df.columns: df[col] = df[col].apply(maybe_evaluate). I appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing safe `eval` ourselves we can also take advantage that `pandas` already provides such implementation:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column1': ['70', '60+3', '80', '90+5', '45-4', '50+5', '50-5'],
    'column2': ['90', '50', '30-4', '40+7', '60', '56', '32+20']
})
```

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.eval(df[col])
```

Or with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df = df.apply(pd.eval)
```

Either produce `df`:

```
  column1 column2
0      70      90
1      63      50
2      80      26
3      95      47
4      41      60
5      55      56
6      45      52
```

---

[`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) will:

> Evaluate a Python expression as a string using various backends.

> The following arithmetic operations are supported: +, -, *, /, **, %, // (python engine only) along with the following boolean operations: | (or), & (and), and ~ (not). Additionally, the 'pandas' parser allows the use of and, or, and not with the same semantics as the corresponding bitwise operators. Series and DataFrame objects are supported and behave as they would with plain ol’ Python evaluation.

The "string cannot contain any Python [statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#simple-statements), only Python expressions."

Comment: Should've known Pandas would include this... :D

Comment: It's a nifty little function. It was originally introduced for performant evaluation since it tries `numexpr` first before using the `python` engine. But it has the benefit of also being "safe" ish. =)

Comment: Hi Henry, Thanks for suggestion. Is there anyway I could apply this pd.eval function to csv file after I read as df = pd.read_csv("xyz.csv") instead of pd.DataFrame()? It consistently giving me error "ValueError: unknown type object"